# Create a LVM with disk full of data

Tags: lvm

I'm starting with LVM and I would like to know if when I create a LVM with different disks and one of them has data, when I create virtual volumes will make me loose all the data stored. And if there is a way to don't lose it, how can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you reassign your drive into an LVM, it will loose the data. Preventing this can be easy if you have at least one empty disk with enough space to accomodate the data: Just add the empty disk into the LVM, copy the data over there and after that is finished, reassign the full drive into the LVM as well.

Depending on your specific goals this might be more complicated or time-consuming (e.g. if a RAID will be used) but generally it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks my thoughts were in that way, create a new LVM with other disk, transfer all the data, and then add the old disk to the LVM to get more space in the logic volume. What I expect is to don't need to copy all the files between LVM and physical volumes, but I suppose this is not possible as you said. 400GB is not "too much", but it will take a few hours.